# spring jpa finds beans that do not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've a spring-boot (2.7.16) app, that throws a `DuplicateMappingException` for a bean that does not exists.

```
org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: The [de.xxxxx.adapter.rest.Mandant] and [de.xxxxx.persistence.jpa.MandantEntity] entities share the same JPA entity name: [mandant] which is not allowed!
```

But there is no Class/Interface/File named `de.xxxxx.adapter.rest.Mandant`.
And there is also no other config containing the string `de.xxxxx.adapter.rest.Mandant`.

I have no idea what hibernate is trying to tell me.

Comment: But i'm using JdbcTemplate in some DAO's.

Comment: The class must be in the class path. Maybe in a jar that is included as dependency

Comment: The error doesn't lie so those classes are somewhere in your classpath. Judging from the partial packages it also feels like the `Mandant` class wrongly has the JPA annotations.

Answer (score 0):

solved by using the annotation `@EntityScan`:

```
@EntityScan({"de.xxxxxx.persistence.jpa", "de.xxxxxx.domain"})
```

I still don't understand where the entity came from, but what is certain is that the package `*adapter.rest` should not be searched.